# Using service account for Google Sheet API with no need of action in web browser

Tags: google-api

When I want to use service account for connection with Google Sheets API I see in web browser:

Is there a way to use this service account without need to user's action like clicking in web browser?

Comment: I think that your goal can be achieved. When you want to use Sheets API with the service account, there are following 2 patterns. 1. Create new Spreadsheet using the service account. By this, the Spreadsheet can be used using Sheets API with the service account. 2. Share the existing Google Spreadsheet with the email of the service account. In this case, the Spreadsheet in your Google Drive can be used. By this, the Spreadsheet can be used using Sheets API with the service account. I post it as a comment because I'm not sure whether this is the direction you expect.

Comment: For bothe patterns, the user is not required to authorization using the browser.